# Call user func array error when trying to insert to mysql

Tags: php, mysqli

I have an insert function which I use for most of my inserts. It looks like this:

```
//insert function
    public function insert($prep, $table, $data) {

          $columns = "";
              $values = array();
          $val = array();

        foreach ($data as $column => $value) {
                  $columns .= ($columns == '') ? '' : ', ';
                  $columns .= $column;
                  $values[$column] = &$data[$column];
        }

        $a = str_repeat('?, ', count($data) );
        $b = substr_replace($a, '', -2);

        $q = $this->mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO $table ($columns) VALUES ($b)");
        call_user_func_array( array($q, 'bind_param'), array_merge(array($prep), $values) );
        $q->execute();
        $q->close();

        //return the last ID used in the database.
        return $this->mysqli->insert_id;

        $this->mysqli->close();
}
```

The above function works without any problems for all inserts. All I need to do is:

```
$db = new Db();

  $data = array(
    "message_title" => "'$this->messageTitle'",
    "message_body" => "'$this->messageBody'",
    "sender_id" => $this->senderID,
    "receiver_id" => $this->receiverID,
    "message_date" => date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
  );

$db->insert('ssiis', 'messages', $data);
```

But I'm getting an error when I try adding to a new table which will hold searches.

```
public function addSearchTerm($searchTerm, $user_id, $today) {

$addSearch = array();

$addSearch = array(
  "user_id" => $user_id,
  "term" => $searchTerm,
  "search_date" => $today
);

$prep = 'iss';

$this->db->insert($prep, 'search_tems', $addSearch);

}
```

Some var_dumps for the insert function.

```
var_dump($columns);
string(26) "user_id, term, search_date" 

var_dump($b);
string(7) "?, ?, ?"

var_dump($values); 
array(3) { ["user_id"]=> &int(64) ["term"]=> &string(9) "Wolverine" ["search_date"]=> &string(19) "2014-12-01 10:12:50" }
```

And the warning

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, first array member is not a valid class name or object in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/com/classes/Db.class.php on line 169 Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/com/classes/Db.class.php on line 170

Comment: What is the output of print_r($q);

Comment: Weird ... It won't display anything.

Comment: `var_dump` gives `bool(false)`

Comment: That is the problem... there is a problem with your query and thus, the $q instead of an object is false, so false->bind_param() is not callable...

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: Hmmm ... I ll recreate the table. See what happens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65981/discussion-between-cito-and-ciprian).